# Нужно ли подключать reset.css в html файл, если подключаешь Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Осваиваю Bootstrap, и задался вопросом: если я подключаю Bootstrap, то нужно ли подключать дополнительно reset.css? Не переопределит ли reset стили бутстрапа? Стоит подключить reset ПЕРЕД подключением Bootstrap? Или не стоит, и у него (бутстрапа) уже есть какие то свои стили сброса?

Comment: Я бы ни то, ни другое не подключал)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/reboot/

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что не так с бутстрапом?

Comment: _нужно ли подключать дополнительно reset.css?_ Надумали использовать bootstrap - используйте его, не надо другое подключать

Comment: @entithat, с ним всё норм, просто если есть кастомный дизайн, то всё равно толку мало, а если нет, то мне и браузерные стили нравятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многие утверждают, что использование reset.css не очень хорошая практика в связи с очень "глубоким" обнулением стилей (в сравнении с normalize.css), что может создать дополнительные сложности в дальнейшей стилизации. Bootstrap содержит в себе normalize.css По сему, если и используете данную библиотеку, то рациональнее было бы не подключать reset.css, а то, что хотите "обнулить" - сделайте ручками.